# Create drawable rotate 180 degree

Tags: android, user-interface, drawable

Is possible to create a button or textview inside of xml LinearLayout rotated 180 degrees?

I tried the animation but the drawable return to 0 degree after the first circle of animation.  How might I address this issue?

Comment: I don't think you can do it in XML - but you should be able to do it in the code by getting the bitmap of the drawable, rotating it and setting back into the view.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

we can create a drawable that is rotated of any number of degree like this..create a drawable file like this..

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher2"
android:fromDegrees="180"
android:toDegrees="180"
android:visible="true" />
```

define this file in the any drawable folder

if this file name is rotate then..

In button `android:background="@drawable/rotate"`

Comment: and to assign this xml to a button for example?

Comment: last problem... i want mantain the default style of button... i try to delete the android:drawable proprieties but it crash..

Comment: lifesaver for me.

Answer (score 7):

you could also set the android:scaleY="-1" in the xml for your button. That would flip the whole view 180 degrees by the Y or change it to scale X to "mirror" it for example. Not a rotation but would flip it 180 degrees for sure.

Comment: This wont' work if I have a background for a textview. It will flip the text as well.